# Laurent expansion for $1/\cos(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

I have a quick question.

[How to find the Laurent expansion for $1/\cos(z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404649/how-to-find-the-laurent-expansion-for-1-cosz)

In the link above the person asks how to find the Laurent expansion for $\frac{1}{cos(z)}$.

The accepted answer utilizes the fact that \begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sin t}&=\frac{1}{ t-\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^5}{5!}-\frac{t^7}{7!}+\dots } \\
                &=\frac{1}{t}\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{t^2}{3!}-\frac{t^4}{5!}+\frac{t^6}{7!}+\dots\right)}\\
                &=\frac{1}{t}\left[1+\left(\frac{t^2}{3!}-\frac{t^4}{5!}+\frac{t^6}{7!}+\dots\right)+\left(\frac{t^2}{3!}-\frac{t^4}{5!}+\frac{t^6}{7!}+\dots\right)^2+\dots\right]\\
                &=t^{-1}+\frac{1}{3!}t+\left[\left(\frac{1}{3!}\right)^2-\frac{1}{5!}\right]t^3+\dots
\end{align}

Fair enough. However, I'm not sure how the person motivates that $|\frac{t^2}{3!}-\frac{t^4}{5!}+\frac{t^6}{7!}+\dots| < 1$ (which is necessary for the above calculation to be valid, i.e. the part of writing $\frac{1}{1-\frac{t^2}{3!}-\frac{t^4}{5!}+\frac{t^6}{7!}+\dots}$ as a geometric series).

This may be obvious but I cant seem to figure it out. It feels valid to say that it should be less than one, but how do you show this?

Thanks!

Comment: In the case of $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\dots$, how do you know that $|x|<1$ for sure?

Comment: Surely at $t=3\pi/2$, the series is $\left|\frac{\sin(t)-t}{t}\right|=\frac{2}{3\pi}+1>1$?

Comment: And surely you'd only have $\left|\sum\right|<1$ when $\frac{\sin t}{t}>0$?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple justification:
$$1-\left(\frac{t^2}{3!}-\frac{t^4}{5!}+\frac{t^6}{7!}-\dotsm\right)=\frac{\sin t}t,$$
so that $\enspace\dfrac{t^2}{3!}-\dfrac{t^4}{5!}+\dfrac{t^6}{7!}-\dotsm=1-\dfrac{\sin t}t$, and it is well-known the cardinal sine function
$$\operatorname{sinc}(t)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin t}t&\text{if }t\ne 0\\1&\text{if }t=0\end{cases}$$
has values in $[0,1]\:$ for all $|t|\le\frac\pi2$.